# Are there non-military inductors with 5 bands?

Tags: identification, inductor

I pulled apart an IKEA lamp tonight, and found this component marked L1, but it has 5 bands - orange, black, red, silver, red - and there's no double width silver in sight:

[image: inductor or resistor?]

What have I found?

Comment: I would guess a 3mH +/-10% inductor and the extra red band means little or nothing. What does it measure?

Comment: probably yes ... what exactly do you want to know?

Comment: @spehroPefhany I think it's part of regulating the transformer output to ~90V, to feed the LEDs but I'm away from home and squinting too hard to trace the tracks properly. I'm hoping to drop it to a lower wattage so it's better suited to a bedroom.

Comment: @jsotola I mostly wanted to check what it was - I've not seen an inductor with an extra band and wondered if it was a flux capacitor. :)

Comment: then ask `what is this?` ... not `Are there non-military inductors with 5 bands?`

Comment: Other than the L1 marking any chance the part is actually a low value 2% resistor?  Maybe just a substitute for an inductor where the small resistance was more important then the inductance value, or could the L1 marking belong to the component to the side?